# How to solve "TLS required to proceed for this domain" with java mail

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I have a very simple task. Send an email from a spring boot application.
The config is straightforward.

```yaml
spring:
  mail:
    host: <our host>
    username: <our user name>
    password: <the password>
    port: 587
    properties:
      mail:
        debug: true
        smtp:
          auth: true
          ssl:
            protocols: TLSv1.2
          starttls:
            enabled: true
```

I tested the standard implementation of Java Mail against Hetzner and Gmail and it works without any problems.

Using the T-Systems SMTP server we see an error.

```
DEBUG: Jakarta Mail version 1.6.7
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "the-smtp-server", port 587, isSSL false
220 the-smtp-server ESMTP
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "the-smtp-server", port: 587
EHLO comstar-backend-deployment-584b9b68d8-crb7p
250-the-smtp-server Hello comstar-backend-deployment-584b9b68d8-crb7p [10.55.238.32]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-PIPE_CONNECT
250-AUTH LOGIN
250-CHUNKING
250-STARTTLS
250 HELP
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "SIZE", arg "52428800"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "8BITMIME", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPELINING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "PIPE_CONNECT", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "AUTH", arg "LOGIN"
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "CHUNKING", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "STARTTLS", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: Found extension "HELP", arg ""
DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect login, host=the-smtp-server, user=<username>, password=<non-null>
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate using mechanisms: LOGIN PLAIN DIGEST-MD5 NTLM XOAUTH2 
DEBUG SMTP: Using mechanism LOGIN
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG SMTP: AUTH LOGIN succeeded
DEBUG SMTP: use8bit false
MAIL FROM:<...>
250 OK
RCPT TO:<...>
550 TLS required to proceed for this domain
RCPT TO:<...>
550 TLS required to proceed for this domain
DEBUG SMTP: Invalid Addresses
DEBUG SMTP:   ...
DEBUG SMTP:   ...
DEBUG SMTP: Sending failed because of invalid destination addresses
RSET
250 Reset OK
DEBUG SMTP: MessagingException while sending, THROW: 
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 TLS required to proceed for this domain
```

Any ideas what I can do to find out the problem?

How can I see the ciphers used?

Answer (score 0):

This config solved the problem

```yaml
spring:
  mail:
    host: <our host>
    port: 587
    properties:
      mail:
        debug: true
        smtp:
          starttls:
            enabled: true
            required: true
```

I don't understand why the server and client don't negotiate this between themselves, since they both seem to know TLS.
Instead you have to set starttls to required.
The debug config is not needed and in our case also authentication is not needed because the traffic is internally routed...